# iPhone, how do I get the device short date format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've not got the device price format setting.

```
NSNumber *temp = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:dblPrice];
NSDecimalNumber *someAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[temp decimalValue]];

NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

return [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:someAmount];
```

How do I get the short date setting ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```